# ActiveDirectory Startup/Shutdown PowerShell Script not being executed, failing silently

Tags: active-directory, powershell, group-policy, windows-server-2012, startup-scripts

**Environment**

- Windows Server 2012 domain
- Windows 10 version 2004 client

I'm trying to deploy an ActiveDirectory Startup or Shutdown powershell script on a test OU to update VLC Media Player and I can't figure out why the powershell isn't running.

I'm using [this article](http://woshub.com/running-powershell-startup-scripts-using-gpo/) as a template, specifically the trick of running `powershell.exe` as a Script Name and the parameters below as the Script Parameters to workaround the Execution Policy.

They are configured using Group Policy > Computer Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Scripts (Startup/Shutdown) in a GPO called "Deploy Active Directory scripts":

- Script Name: `%windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`
- Script Parameters: `-NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass –NoProfile -File "%~dp0Update_VLC.ps1"`

`Update_VLC.ps1` has been saved in the appropriate `\Machine\Scripts\` folders and the appropriate computer secutury group has Read/Execute permissions on it. The GPOs seem to be configured correctly because:

1. When I run `gpresult` on the client it reports

> Settings
>
> > Policies
> >
> > > Windows Settings
> > >
> > > > Scripts
> > > >
> > > > > Startup
> > > > >
> > > > > > Name | Parameters | Last Run | Script Order in GPO | Winning DPO
> > > > > >
> > > > > > `%windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` | `-NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -File "%~dp0Update_VLC.ps1"` | `21/07/2020 2:47:10 PM` | `Not configured` | `Deploy Active Directory Scripts`

2. When I use `psexec -i -s cmd.exe` to troubleshoot on the client by running the script from the same location in the context of the computer's LocalSystem account it works.

I've also tried running a `.cmd` as the script file to run the powershell command. The `.cmd` file itself executes but the powershell invocation within it fails silently, even when redirecting output to a file.

Any advice appreciated.

**EDIT:** an update.

I got this to work with a `.cmd` file after all (typo in my original `.cmd`) with the invocation:

```
%windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -File %~dp0Update_VLC.ps1
```

It does not seem to work using those same arguments entered for *Name* and *Parameters* in **Scripts (Startup/Shutdown)** as follows:

Script Name: `%windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`

Script Parameters: `-NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass –NoProfile -File %~dp0Update_VLC.ps1`

There may be a typo in what I'm using that I can't see (if so, I would be grateful if anyone could point it out). Or the direct approach suggested in [link](http://woshub.com/running-powershell-startup-scripts-using-gpo/) (as opposed to using a Windows Command Script) doesn't work. Happy for feedback on either.

Comment: This may have to to with the script itself. How does ist look like?

Comment: Thanks, @bjoster. It's not the script, I think. Even if I comment everything out so the only line executing is `Start-Transcript -NoClobber -IncludeInvocationHeader -OutputDirectory c:\temp` it still doesn't run.

Comment: Are "Read" and "Execute" permissions given on the PS1 file (or foder)? CMD ignores execute and runs perfectly with 'read', but PS honors taht correctly.